# ERROR in ./.nuxt/App.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader'

Tags: vue.js, heroku, npm, nuxt.js

I tried deploying my Nuxt project folder to Heroku and I keep getting this error. The main setup of this project is combination of Laravel and NuxtJS, and I am using this boilerplate https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-nuxt

This is what the build log looks like:

```
ERROR in ./.nuxt/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader' in '/tmp/build_3edb4cd6b283c552d7684236bf31a7e7'
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js 11:0-40
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js
ERROR in ./client/layouts/admin.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader' in '/tmp/build_3edb4cd6b283c552d7684236bf31a7e7'
 @ ./client/layouts/admin.vue 4:0-66
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js
```

In my local machine, `npm run build` works fine. But when I do `git push heroku master`, I am getting this error.

This is what my **package.json** looks like:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt -c client/nuxt.config.js",
    "build": "nuxt build -c client/nuxt.config.js",
    "start": "nuxt start -c client/nuxt.config.js",
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue client/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/coreui": "^3.2.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.26",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@nuxtjs/router": "^1.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.11.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.19.0",
    "vform": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.15.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^1.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "pug": "^3.0.0",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?  Im not sure whether im just supposed to move sass loader into dependancies rather than dev dependencies but that doesn't feel right.